# Can I power a 12V solenoid valve with a 24V supply

Tags: solenoid-valve

I am trying to control a 12V solenoid valve with a 24V supply. Will it work and what are the potential dangers?

Here is the part: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/solenoid-variants-pneumatic-electric-without/dp/B08CZRLT7D/ref=sr_1_19?dchild=1&keywords=magnet-2+wege+magnetventil&qid=1633789500&sr=8-19

The solenoid will be controlled via a [MOS Module Relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GLNCRR4)

[image]

Comment: Why yes, certainly -- if you don't mind it burning up after a while.  Unless you do it properly.  Can you *edit your question* with a description or a schematic of *how* you plan on driving the solenoid (i.e., transistor, switch, a relay, whatever).  Then instead of just saying "of course it'll work if you do it properly" we can tell you the right flavor or "properly".

Comment: Updated with a schematic of how it will look.

Comment: With 24 V, the relay will be getting 4x the expected power, so it will probably overheat if left on for more than a few 10s of seconds. Shorter than that, you may get away with it, as long as you have a long cool down in between. If you want it to last long time, then the Pi could PWM it at 50% duty cycle, or you could place a dropper resistor in series, either of which could halve the voltage to a safe dissi[ation level.

Comment: Is there any chance of using a 12 V supply instead? The diagram doesn't show the 24 V being used for anything else. Otherwise, you could get a small buck convertor with a 12 V output, or, as the solenoid coil is rated for 100 mA at 12 V, use a 2 W 120 Ω resistor in series with the coil (it will get hot and waste 1.2 W of energy).

Comment: @AndrewMorton the 24V is being used for other parts in the unit, but I just didn't show it in the schematic.

Comment: The seller [has a business address](https://www.amazon.de/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=A1PA6795UKMFR9&orderID=&protocol=current&seller=A3B8GCWPRWBH74&sshmPath=).  Fire up Google Earth and see if that looks like a Czech solenoid factory.  If it looks like an apartment or a mail drop-box or a lawyer office (I see a whole lot of those when investigating Amazon 3rd party sellers), then the actual factory is in Shenzhen, China. .  In that case, any CE marks are lies and that's on you, because *you're the importer*.

Comment: @Neil_UK for the same power it would need PWM at 25%, which if combined with flyback diode, could work.

Comment: @Jasen Yes, I wondered about that. You're correct for a resistor of course, I was assuming that in a relay the inductance dominated and so the effect is to ratio the effective voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pull of a solenoid is a function of the current going through it.  Once the solenoid has pulled in, it acts like a resistor: its current is proportional to the applied voltage divided by the coil resistance.

That's a 100mA, 12V solenoid, which implies a 120\$\Omega\$ resistance.  If you drove it from 24V, it would consume four times as much power when it is engaged.  With that sort of solenoid, that just means it'll pull harder, but get a lot hotter.  If you only ever actuated it briefly (a few seconds at a time, and at 1/4 it's rated duty cycle*), then you could just drive it from 24V directly.

To operate that solenoid within its ratings from a 24V supply, you need to use a 120\$\Omega\$ resistor in series with it.  That'll cut the current down to 100mA, and let you run the solenoid for as long as it would run without a resistor from 12V.

Since you're buying that solenoid from a completely unknown source, you're responsible for verifying that it doesn't get hot when you run the thing as you intend.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPkoKN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

* That thing doesn't *have* a rated duty cycle.  Assuming it were rated for 100% on, then you'd have to have it on no more than 1/4 of the time.

Comment: Windings have impedance not resistance... but, yeah.  This is the answer.  The voltage regulation will be imperfect, but more than good enough for a coil winding.

Comment: A better wording is "windings have impedance *and not just* resistance".  But when it's DC -- it's resistance.  Otherwise you'll have to go around pointing out that resistors have impedance, too, which also doesn't matter at DC.

Comment: True, the difference only arises durning switch-on and switch-off.  (although at switch-off, it pales by comparison to the inductive kick).

Answer (score 0):

PWM is an accepted way of doing this .Solenoids have lots of inductance which smoothes the DC current waveform when a squarewave pulsing from zero to 24VDC is applied at a sufficient frequency.This means that a 50% duty cycle square wave of applied voltage will make the solenoid think that it is getting 12V .This wastes far less power than a resistor and PWM is easy to generate .Remember to use a freewheel diode across your  coil  if you do this. The actual PWM frequency is not critical .If too low you will get chatter ,if too high you will get switching losses and make things more difficult for yourself .On the relays and solenoids that I have done 100Hz has caused chatter .I have run things between 2 and 30KHz .

Comment: That might work into an inductor (though the inductor will resist changes in current obviously).  It would not work on a resistive load.  2x voltage = 4x power.   4x power *half the time* is too much.